# Using setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled for remote debugging

Tags: google-chrome, cordova, remote-debugging

Is it possible to use Chrome remote debugging for a cordova app luanhched from visual studio using the setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled static method of the WebView class.

I really need to debug issues but can't find any other way.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What android version are you using? It should work by default for android 4.4 I believe (using cordova 3.4.1)

Comment: 4.3 at the moment, it's a Galaxy S3, not sure if a 4.4 update is available somehow?  It done a whole bunch of updates recently, I'll see if I can get it up to 4.4 and try again.